# Probability of failing a test or passing, different scenarios.

Tags: probability, proof-verification

The probability to fail a drive test is $t$ while the probability to pass a drive test is $t+0.2$. I really need to know if what I am doing is correct. I guess I should be using bernoulli but I don't know how.

a. What is the probability to pass?

Sol: $0.6$.

b. Let Donna, David, Johnny and Natalie be four random people. What is the probability that exactly two people pass the test?

Sol: $4\cdot(0.6\cdot 0.6\cdot 0.4 \cdot 0.4)$ (Of that one I am really not sure).

c. Given only two of the four has passed the test, what is the probability those were Donna and Johnny?

Sol: Every one of them has either failed or passed where the chance is $50\%$. The probability it is Johnny is $0.5$, while the probability it is Johnny and Donna is $0.5\cdot 0.5$.

d. Is the probability that at least one of the four passes the test greater than the probability that at least one of the four fails?

That one I don't remember how to solve. I can do it using discrete mathematics but that is not the point. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: For (b) you should probably be multiplying by ${4\choose 2}=6$ rather than by $4$.  So for (c) it should be $\frac16$

Comment: For (d), one approach would be to look at the probabilities they all fail or all pass.  Alternatively, just note that passing is more likely than failing.

Comment: Henry, I changed (c). I was wrong at the beginning. Only two passed.

Comment: And thank you by the way... 
I hope I have done no wrong. I see I am being disliked.

Comment: It was not me who downvoted your question

Comment: I didn't say so...

Comment: Now that I changed (c) it makes a difference, right?

Comment: For (d) I would calculate 1 - Pr(all four fail) and 1-Pr(all four pass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)** is correct

**(b)**, as the comments say, should be $\binom{4}{2} 0.6^2 0.4^2$. $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ is the number of possible pairs candidates who pass, i.e. $\{Donna,David\}$,$\{Donna,Johnny\}$,$\{Donna,Natalie\}$,$\{David,Johnny\}$,$\{David,Natalie\}$ or $\{Johnny,Natalie\}$.

**(c)** You already know how many people have passed, the questions is if it where exactly Donna and Johnny. The above shows that there are 6 possible ways in which exactly two people can pass, the probability of any specific pair is thus $\frac{1}{6}$.

**(d)** Compute it. The probability that at least one passes is the same as the probability that not all four fail. The probability of that is $\binom{4}{0} 0.4^4 0.6^0 = \frac{256}{10000} = 0.0256$, meaning the probability that at least one candidate passes is $1-0.0256$ = $0.9764$.

The probability that at least one candidate fails is the same as the probability that not all four pass, which is $\binom{4}{4} 0.4^0 0.6^4 = 0.1296$. The probability of at least one candidate failing is thus $0.8704$.

The answer is thus yes, the probabilit of one candidate passing is greater than the probability of at least one failing.

Comment: What did you take P to be?

Comment: $p=0.6$, i.e. the probability of passing. But you can of course equally well use $p=0.4$, and put the number of failing people, instead of the number of passing people, in $\binom{4}{\cdot}$.

Answer (score 1):

a.

- $t+t+0.2=1 \implies t=0.4$
- The probability to fail is $0.4$
- The probability to pass is $0.6$

b.

- Choose $2$ out of the group of $4$ people
- Multiply it by the probability that they pass
- Choose $2$ out of the remaining $2$ people
- Multiply it by the probability that they fail
- The overall probability is $\binom42\cdot(0.6)^2\cdot\binom22\cdot(0.4)^2=0.3456$

c.

- There are $\binom42=6$ pairs of $2$ out of $4$ people
- Hence the probability for a specific pair is $\frac16$

d.

- The probability that at least $1$ out of $4$ will pass the test is $1-(0.4)^4=0.9744$
- The probability that at least $1$ out of $4$ will fail the test is $1-(0.6)^4=0.8704$